# Unable to print data in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, webdriver

My aim is to extract data from multiple link on single site, but problem that i am facing is prints empty array after 3 link. It prints result from 1 to 2 then after 2nd link it prints empty array then again prints non empty array. also my code is in running state. it does not stop after 72nd hyperlink.
with this it goes to 700 with empty array.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
suit =[]
url=["https://sehat.com.pk/products/After-Biotic-Cap-30%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Amybact-Powder-Sachets-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Bactocell-Probiotic-Sachet-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/BC%252d2Bio-Oral-Susp-2billion%7B47%7D5ml-",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Bio%252dKult-Candea-Cap-60%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Bio%252dKult-Infantis-Sachet-16%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Bio%252dKult-Multi%252dStrain-Cap-30%27s.h",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/DiaResQ-Sachet-3%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Doctile-powder-Sachet-3g-30%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enterogermina-2-Billion%7B47%7D5ml-Oral-Su",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enterogermina-4-Billion%7B47%7D5ml-Oral-Su",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enterogermina-Oral-Susp-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Ezegut-Probiotic-Drops-5ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Gravinate-Liq-12.5mg%7B47%7D4ml-60ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Orsiflor%252dZ-Sachet-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Prepro%252dgg-Sachets-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Proflor-Oral-Susp-8Ampx5ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Prohale-Chewable-Tab-2-Billion-CFU-30%27s.",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/S-%281%252d4%29--%28Diarrhea-Food-Poisonin",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enterogermina-Oral-Susp-20Ampx5ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enflor-Cap-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enflor-Powder-Sachet-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Ecotec-Cap-180mg-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Ecotec-Powder-Sachet-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Gravinate-Liq-12.5mg%7B47%7D4ml-120ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Gravinate-Tab-50mg-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Gravinate-Tab-50mg-100%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Gutcare-Cap-420mg%7B47%7D500mg-12%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Gutcare-Powder-Sachets-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Uflora-Cap-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Probact-lozenges-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Smecta-Powder-Sachet-1%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Smecta-Powder-Sachet-30%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Actiflor-Powder-Sachet-250mg-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Pro%252dBerry-Probiotics-Cap-14%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Pro%252dZ-Probiotic-Cap-14%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Gutshine-Powder-Sachet-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Newflora-Cap-25%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Diosecta-Powder-Sachet-3gm-30%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Neo-Q%252dpalgite-Susp-120ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Neo-Q%252dplex-Susp-120ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Neo-Q%252dplex-Z--Susp-120ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Olomine-DS-Eye-Drops-0.1%25-5ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/I%252dMenate-Syp-12.5mg%7B47%7D5ml-60ml.ht",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/I%252dMenate-Tab-50mg-10x10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/I%252dMenate-Tab-50mg-10x25%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/UNETOX%252dT-Tab-500mg-100%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/UNETOX%252dT-Tab-500mg-500%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/DAVISSALTS-Sachet-40%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Dymin-Syp-12.5mg%7B47%7D4ml-60ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Dymin-Tab-50mg-100%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Ezegut-Drops-10ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Libs-Cap-20%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/KAOTIN-Susp-120ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/KAOTIN-Susp-450ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/KAOTIN-Susp-60ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/PAEDITROL-Sachet-27.9gm.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Floraid-Cap-250mg-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Floraid-Powder-Sachet-250mg-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/BABY%252dS-Sachet-1%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/BANTOX-Tab-500mg-100%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/BEETOX-Tab-500mg-100%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Bifilor-Sachet-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/C%252dNate-Inj-50mg-25Ampx1ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/DIROSAL-Sachet-28.4gm.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enfamil--AR-Powder-400g.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enfamil-O%252dLac-Powder-400g.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Entox%252dP-Tab-500mg-100%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/KAOMAGMA-Susp-90ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/KEMYPUGITE-Susp1.0mg%7B47%7D10ml-60ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/KEMYTRAL-Powder-1%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/KEYTIN-Susp-60ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/NEPECTOL-Syp-60ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/ORALYTE-Powder-Sachets-20%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/SEVIDOXINE-Tab-100%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/After-Biotic-Cap-30%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Amybact-Powder-Sachets-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Bactocell-Probiotic-Sachet-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/BC%252d2Bio-Oral-Susp-2billion%7B47%7D5ml-",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Bio%252dKult-Candea-Cap-60%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Bio%252dKult-Infantis-Sachet-16%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Bio%252dKult-Multi%252dStrain-Cap-30%27s.h",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/DiaResQ-Sachet-3%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Doctile-powder-Sachet-3g-30%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enterogermina-2-Billion%7B47%7D5ml-Oral-Su",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enterogermina-4-Billion%7B47%7D5ml-Oral-Su",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enterogermina-Oral-Susp-10%27s.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Ezegut-Probiotic-Drops-5ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Gravinate-Liq-12.5mg%7B47%7D4ml-60ml.html",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Orsiflor%252dZ-Sachet-10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Prepro%252dgg-Sachets-10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Proflor-Oral-Susp-8Ampx5ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Prohale-Chewable-Tab-2-Billion-CFU-30%27s",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/S-%281%252d4%29--%28Diarrhea-Food-Poisoni",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enterogermina-Oral-Susp-20Ampx5ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enflor-Cap-10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enflor-Powder-Sachet-10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Ecotec-Cap-180mg-10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Ecotec-Powder-Sachet-10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Gravinate-Liq-12.5mg%7B47%7D4ml-120ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Gravinate-Tab-50mg-10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Gravinate-Tab-50mg-100%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Gutcare-Cap-420mg%7B47%7D500mg-12%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Gutcare-Powder-Sachets-10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Uflora-Cap-10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Probact-lozenges-10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Smecta-Powder-Sachet-1%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Smecta-Powder-Sachet-30%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Actiflor-Powder-Sachet-250mg-10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Pro%252dBerry-Probiotics-Cap-14%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Pro%252dZ-Probiotic-Cap-14%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Gutshine-Powder-Sachet-10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Newflora-Cap-25%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Diosecta-Powder-Sachet-3gm-30%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Neo-Q%252dpalgite-Susp-120ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Neo-Q%252dplex-Susp-120ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Neo-Q%252dplex-Z--Susp-120ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Olomine-DS-Eye-Drops-0.1%25-5ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/I%252dMenate-Syp-12.5mg%7B47%7D5ml-60ml.h",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/I%252dMenate-Tab-50mg-10x10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/I%252dMenate-Tab-50mg-10x25%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/UNETOX%252dT-Tab-500mg-100%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/UNETOX%252dT-Tab-500mg-500%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/DAVISSALTS-Sachet-40%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Dymin-Syp-12.5mg%7B47%7D4ml-60ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Dymin-Tab-50mg-100%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Ezegut-Drops-10ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Libs-Cap-20%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/KAOTIN-Susp-120ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/KAOTIN-Susp-450ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/KAOTIN-Susp-60ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/PAEDITROL-Sachet-27.9gm.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Floraid-Cap-250mg-10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Floraid-Powder-Sachet-250mg-10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/BABY%252dS-Sachet-1%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/BANTOX-Tab-500mg-100%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/BEETOX-Tab-500mg-100%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Bifilor-Sachet-10%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/C%252dNate-Inj-50mg-25Ampx1ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/DIROSAL-Sachet-28.4gm.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enfamil--AR-Powder-400g.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Enfamil-O%252dLac-Powder-400g.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/Entox%252dP-Tab-500mg-100%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/KAOMAGMA-Susp-90ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/KEMYPUGITE-Susp1.0mg%7B47%7D10ml-60ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/KEMYTRAL-Powder-1%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/KEYTIN-Susp-60ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/NEPECTOL-Syp-60ml.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/ORALYTE-Powder-Sachets-20%27s.htm",
"https://sehat.com.pk/products/SEVIDOXINE-Tab-100%27s.html"]
count=0
for endpoint in url:
    print(count)
    count+=1
    r = requests.get(endpoint)
    time.sleep(6)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    time.sleep(1)
    content = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'Block Moveable Panel PrimaryProductDetails')
    print(content)
```

Comment: Just a heads up that there is no need to `time.sleep()` in either location. You are not working with a "live" page here so there is no need to "wait" for it to be "complete". If you need or want to wait between iterations (to avoid overloading the server for example) then you probably want to do that once at the end of you loop after the `print()`

Comment: On a side-note, have you heard of variables and constants and fstrings! Your code could be way more concise! Also there's no need for a count variable when you can enumerate all your urls! :)

Comment: You should really make a simple example, that has maybe 2 or 3 links, not the humongous list you have. That way you could also test is it because 2nd or 3rd link does it, or is it that a particular link doesn't work with your code.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes BeautifulSoup can't always find what you are looking for, so it returns an empty array, since soup.find_all returns an array of all the results.

This could be because the page it requested just doesn't have the, in this case, product you are looking for.